# I have multiple dictionaries that I can use but want to be able to know the size of each

Tags: java, dictionary

I am working on a program and I have 3 possible dictionaries that I could use in it. One of the things I am asked to do in the program is to find the size of the dictionary that is being used. I have a constructor that looks like this:

```
public SpellChecker(String dictFilename, boolean ignoreCase) throws FileNotFoundException {
    SpellChecker spellChecker = new SpellChecker(dictFilename, false);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("english-dict.txt"));
    dictFilename = input.useDelimiter("\\Z").nextLine();
}
```

I was wondering if `dictFilename` could be inside the new file object that way whatever the input was it would use the correct file (if it existed) and then I could turn around and get the length of that file and assign its size to an int variable. That way the size method that I have could just return the size of the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've hard coded `"english-dict.txt"` when constructing your `Scanner`.

Pass in `dictFilename` instead?

Comment: I was also wondering is the last line in the constructor a good place for that or should I put that in another method?

Comment: It seems like you should be using a different variable for that result. No?

Comment: I think so. But I am also wondering how am I going to get the size of the dictionary if it is in the constructor. I know that File objects have methods like exist(), canRead(), and length(), and I was wondering if there is a way to use these in my size method? As of right now I can't because it is within the constructor.

Comment: Create an instance variable in the class. Lets call it `foo`. Then in the constructor say `foo = dictFileName`. Or something like that.

Comment: So something like new File(file) then say file= dictFilename?